# Insert element in XHTML

Tags: jquery, html, xhtml

I have a problem in XHTML, I tested this code in HTML and work it.

**index.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Load</title>
        <!-- Libreria jQuery -->
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#botton").click(function(event) {
                    $("#cap").load('test.xhtml #content');
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="cap">Click here...</div>
    <br/>
    <input id="botton" type="button" value="update" />
    </body>
</html>
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Content</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">Show content, YES.</div>
      <div id="hidden">I don't show</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This XHTML no work it. error console:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The provided markup is invalid XML, and therefore cannot be inserted into an XML document.**

HTML works, but does not work in XHTML, right is valid XHTML insert elements?, thank you all.

Comment: where is your `#cap`? You have only `#capa`

Comment: name=boton, id=botton, type=button? Seriously?

Comment: ups!. "id" and "type", I deleted "name".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your code is not according to xhtml standards.

see http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_xhtml.asp

## The Most Important Differences from HTML:

#### Document Structure

- XHTML DOCTYPE is mandatory
- The xmlns attribute in  is mandatory
- html, head, title, and body tags are mandatory

#### XHTML Elements

- XHTML elements must be properly nested
- XHTML elements must always be closed
- XHTML elements must be in lowercase
- XHTML documents must have one root element

#### XHTML Attributes

- Attribute names must be in lower case
- Attribute values must be quoted
- Attribute minimization is forbidden

Comment: The xhtml is valided.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">, this is XHTML DOCTYPE.

http://www.htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/doctype.html

Answer (score 2):

I believe this may be a flaw in the jQuery function, but it does work when you remove the DOCTYPE declaration from the include file.

If the include file is not meant to be displayed as a stand-alone XHTML file, it will suffer no adverse effect from this removal.
And if it is, well, note that you don't need a DOCTYPE declaration in XHTML files for making them display in standards mode; XHTML files are always displayed in standards mode. The only compatibility problem you'd get is when you'd use named entity references such as `&nbsp;` in the file.